# Достать все сообщения с публичного чата Telegram

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot, telegram

Как спарсить заданное пользователем количество сообщений с публичного чата Telegram?

На входе пользователь вводит url чата и количество сообщений которое нужно спарсить. Раньше никогда не работал ни с ботами Телеграм, ни с его АПИ. Как лучше это реализовать? Возможно есть готовые библиотеки для данной задачи?

Comment: Вот тут [http://ebot.one/wiki/index.php/Обработка_ботом_сообщений_группы](http://ebot.one/wiki/index.php/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B) - Парсинг групп в telegram через бота, может подойдет и для канала, 100% уверенности нет. Но тут платно

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если нужно парсить с любого рандомного публичного чата, то через Telegram-Bot-API этого не сделать. Потому что бот читает только из чата, куда он добавлен сам.

Для ботов есть только один способ получать сообщения - метод [getUpdates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) получает все сообщения за определенный период, но надо понимать, что в ответ приходит данные по всем чатам и определять нужный придется самостоятельно.

Для понимания как писать именно ботов для Telegram можно почитать вот эту статью - https://netology.ru/blog/bot-php ну или любую другую по запросу `telegram бот на php` их достаточно много=)

Для того что бы парсить из любого чата, нужно писать свой клиент для Telegram, тогда можно будет использовать метод [messages.getHistory()](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getHistory)

Нашел реализацию клиента Telegram на PHP - [MadelineProto](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto), можно попробовать использовать ее.

Дополнительно можно почитать:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687435/telegram-api-with-php-not-bot - в ответах есть краткое описание шагов по созданию клиента для Telegram
https://core.telegram.org/#getting-started - дока по TelegramAPI

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример для Node.JS

```
'use strict'
const { Client } = require('tdlnode');

const configExample = {
    verbosity_level: 1,
    fatal_error_callback: e => { console.log(e) },
}

const api_id = 'ВАШ API ID';
const api_hash = 'ВАШ API HASH';
const phone_number = 'ВАШ ТЕЛЕФОН';

const chatID = 1111111111; // ID чата

const up = async () => {
    const client = new Client({ api_id, api_hash, phone_number }, configExample);
    await client.init();

    await client.fetch({
        '@type': 'getChatHistory',
        'chat_id': chatID,
        'offset': 0,
        'limit': 10,
    }).then( (chatHistory) => {
        console.log(chatHistory);
    });

    client.stop();
}

up();
```

Ваш api_id и api_hash получаете вот тут:
https://my.telegram.org/apps

ID нужного вам чата (канала, бота и т.д.) можно узнать у бота **userinfobot**

Просто из нужного вам чата форвардните этому боту любое сообщение и он вам всё расскажет.

offset и limit назначайте такие, какие вам нужны по логике программы.

Переменная chatHistory - массив объектов. Каждый объект это сообщение.